# localeCompare not working correctly in Safari

Tags: javascript, sorting, safari

I'm using localeCompare to sort several columns of various alphanumeric data. One of the columns is money and localeCompare - in safari only - doesn't sort them correctly. This works in FF, Chrome and IE, but fails in Safari (and therefore IOS)

Am I missing something? There's no error, it just returns the wrong results. I know I can write a custom sort function to handle it, but I was hoping there's a simpler solution...

Example Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Chenzorama/pLav80Ly/

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="sortme">
  <div class="somemoney">$10,231,000</div>
  <div class="somemoney">$18,000,000</div>
  <div class="somemoney">$18,500,030</div>
  <div class="somemoney">$8,765,000</div>
  <div class="somemoney">$100,000,000</div>
</div>
```

and the JS sort function I'm calling is this:

```
 var units = $(".sortme .somemoney");
  units.detach().sort(function(a,b) {
    var aa = $(a).text();
    var bb = $(b).text();
    aa=aa.replace(/[,$]+/g, "").trim();
    bb=bb.replace(/[,$]+/g, "").trim();
    var updown = 0;

    if (sortDir == "ab") {
      updown = aa.localeCompare(bb, "en", {numeric: true});
    } else {
      updown = bb.localeCompare(aa, "en", {numeric: true});
    }
    return updown;
  });

  $(".sortme").append(units);
```

I tried stripping out the dollar sign and commas thinking those were the culprits but that didn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support `String.prototype.localeCompare()`, yet. It still in the technology-preview. I don't know maybe support in the next OSX and iOS.